extract file name and sub subdirectory names as variables from absolute path of file in python
I have a file in python. Path to the path is /home/user/pythonfiles/test_files/test1.py
I want to find the file name and last subdirectories of the file as variables.
I have done like below
# find file name
sess_name = os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0]
print("file name is " + sess_name)

same way I want to capture the last subdirectory name. How do I do that.
Expected output is below
    test_files # this is the last subdirectory I want to capture.
    


Get the directory name and then get the basename of that.

os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(__file__))

Aside: you should switch to PathLib instead of os.path
